building OpenCV with GStreamer on Windows, copy to other computer without install GStreamer on Windows
I want OpenCV-python with GStreamer on Windows.
I once installed GStreamer runtime and GStreamer development, and downloaded the opencv and opencv- contrib sources on a Windows machine.
Using these, I was able to complete the build using CMake in about an hour.
It worked good, but I want to use this program on other Windows machine.
The build process involves downloading a lot of files and generating a lot of files, and my machine doesn't have the free space for it.
Will opencv built with GStreamer be freely copied to other machines so that you can do pip install opencv-python?
Also, a large amount of data remains on the machine where the build was performed, so I would like to delete all but the necessary files.
If I could be greedy, I would be happy if it could be built to be widely compatible with the Python 3.X series.
I successfully built opencv with gstreamer on one machine and it worked as expected.
I would like to delete unnecessary files after building and copy them to other machines.

Instead of creating a whl file, I achieved this by copying the built cv2 folder to another computer or to another directory on the same computer.
Here, the python version is 3.x. If you want to use it on another computer, I recommend that you use the same python version installed on the building computer.
Here's what I did:

Install gstreamer runtime and develop.
CMake settings following below:

  GSTREAMER_...=C:/gstreamer/1.0/msvc_x86_64/lib/...
  OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=C:/path/to/opencv-contrib/modules
  BUILD_opencv_world=ON
  BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF
  OPENCV_GAPI_GSTREAMER=ON
  WITH_GSTREAMER=ON
  PYTHON3_PACKAGES_PATH=C:/myCV/happySitePack <- give it a funny name


Press Generate button.
Set Release, Build "ALL_BUILD" amd "INSTALL" on Visual Studio 2019.(about 1+ hours)
Uninstall "Gstreamer 1.0 Development Files". (because it consumes too much disk space.)
Copy all files from C:/gstreamer/1.0/msvc_x86_64/bin/ to C:/myCV/happySitePack/cv2/python-3.x/.
Copy the folder C:/gstreamer/1.0/msvc_x86_64/lib to C:/myCV/happySitePack/cv2/python-3.x/.
Edit file C:/myCV/happySitePack/cv2/config-3.x.py

import os
file_path=__file__
dir_path=os.path.dirname(file_path)

PYTHON_EXTENSIONS_PATHS = [
    os.path.join(dir_path, 'python-3.x')
] + PYTHON_EXTENSIONS_PATHS

BINARIES_PATHS = [
    os.path.join(dir_path, 'python-3.x')
] + BINARIES_PATHS


All done! You can copy cv2 folder (about 600 MB) to anywhere or other computer.
You can remove build folder (about 30GB).

If you want to configure for other version of python, you can build again (if you uninstalled GStreamer Develop, re-install it.)

Edit CMakeCache.txt (e.g. at C:/myCV/build). You must fix python.exe and python3x.lib path and (3.x.x). You can use Ctrl+F on your editor.
Close Cmake and restart.
hit Configure and Generate and Open Project.
Build > Build > ALL_BUILD and INSTALL on Visual Studio.

If you build for python3.x and python3.y (or more), you should have C:/myCV/happySitePack/cv2/python3.x and cv2/python3.y directory, and cv2/config-3.x.py and cv2/config-3.y.py. You can copy cv2.cp3x-win_amd64.pyd and cv2.cp3y-win_amd64.pyd files to python-3 directory and edit config-3.x.pys like this:
import os
file_path=__file__
dir_path=os.path.dirname(file_path)

PYTHON_EXTENSIONS_PATHS = [
    os.path.join(dir_path, 'python-3')
] + PYTHON_EXTENSIONS_PATHS

BINARIES_PATHS = [
    os.path.join(dir_path, 'python-3')
] + BINARIES_PATHS

You can copy cv2 folder to other computer.

opencv-python says pip install opencv-python comes with its own (statically linked) OpenCV, so in order to use your own, you likely need to build the python wheel as well.
Instructions on how to do that are on the same page in the Manual builds section. (Note that this involves building opencv again from a submodule, not reuses the build results you already have.)
Once your build succeeds, the resulting wheel should be the only thing you need to keep / the file you can use to install on another machine.

@knob I updated my comment when moving it from the staging ground. You seem to have missed the fact that I suggest starting from a different git repository (opencv-python) than you have (opencv+opencv-contribs). You'll have to effectively start over.
